# How do you update the fn project server from the CLI?

Tags: docker, fn

Docker caches the `latest` version on my machine, I know I can do `docker pull` on it, but is there a way to do it via the command line tool?

Comment: What is the "fn project server"? Is it your project? Why to ask such questions here if you is the author?

Comment: It's a common question we get, that's why.

Comment: Project released yesterday: https://blogs.oracle.com/developers/announcing-fn

Answer (score 3):

With the command line tool, you can run:

```
fn update
```

Or without it:

```
docker pull fnproject/functions:latest
```

Answer (score 0):

For Fn CLI V0.5.15 and presumably higher use

`fn update server`